# Why does uint16_t make a difference here?

Tags: c, integer, microcontroller, pic

```
volatile uint16_t r;
unsigned char poly = 0x07;
unsigned char c = 0;

r = (c << 8) ^ poly;
```

When the code is compiled with gcc on Linux, `r` is `7`.
When the same code is compiled by Microchip C18, `r` is `0`.
Why?

If I change it to:

```
volatile uint16_t r;
uint16_t poly = 0x07;
uint16_t c = 0;

r = (c << 8) ^ poly;
```

`r` becomes `7` in C18, too.

There is a section about integer promotion in the C18 manual, but I don't think it has something to do with my question. Anyway, here it is:

> *ISO mandates that all arithmetic be performed at int precision or greater.
>   By default, MPLAB C18 will perform
>   arithmetic at the size of the largest
>   operand, even if both operands are
>   smaller than an int. The ISO mandated
>   behavior can be instated via the -Oi
>   command-line option.*

Comment: What happens on C18 for `r = c ^ poly;` or `r = (0) ^ poly;`? Have you tried the `-Oi` switch as suggested by the manual?

Comment: In both cases it's still 0 but with the -Oi option enabled it is 7.

Comment: Then use `-Oi` and complain to your compiler vendor that their compiler is broken-by-default...

Comment: By the way, with `r = (c << 7) ^ poly`, `r` is 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `c << 8` is undefined in this compiler, the result of xor can't be predicted.  The result could be anything the compiler chooses.

See [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) for an introduction to undefined behavior, especially the section "Oversized Shift Amounts".

Comment: `c<<8` is not undefined on any C implementation.

Comment: @R, standard C will promote to int.  This compiler apparently does not as noted by the OP.  So the operation is essentially an oversized shift, AFAICT.

Comment: I opened a ticket with Microchip to confirm.

Comment: Microchip confirmed that casting c to int is necessary, so the answer seems correct.

Answer (score 2):

c << 8 with c a char is basically sending all the bits to oblivion. As specified in the doc, both c and 8 fit in a char, so everything is done using char.

c << 8UL may change the deal.

Comment: This explains what happens to `c` if any of the bits were set, but doesn't explain why the `^ poly` fragment disappears too.

Comment: Actually, the standard also says that shifting an integer of size `n` bits by `n` is undefined behavior, so who knows what shifting a char by 8 does on this compiler? (note: on a standard compiler, `c<<8` is defined by virtue of the promotion to `int` that this compiler removes)

Comment: Oh, interesting. That explains why the results I am getting are, well, undefined. I even managed to get 0x62 instead of 0x00 and in another variant I got a disassembly that completely ignored that line. That's the answer I guess.